# java border gui

Tags: java, user-interface, applet

I am not good with GUIs or User Interfaces in Java.

Would a Border or JPanel be good for something like the image below?

[image]

So, what would be the best option for me? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on Using [Layout Managers](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html). You can easily nest panels to get the desired effect.

Maybe start with a BorderLayout. Then you can add a panel that uses a GridLayout, which contains all your image tiles, to the CENTER of the BorderLayout. Then you can add the scrollpane containing the text area to the SOUTH. Then you can create another panel to add to the EAST.

Be creative and experiment.

Comment: So essentially it's GridLayouts within BorderLayouts!

Answer (score 0):

You can make 4 seperate panels for a border, using `BorderLayout.NORTH`,`BorderLayout.EAST`,`BorderLayout.SOUTH`,and `BorderLayout.WEST`, This is the easiest way in my opinion.

By the way, in the top right of your picture, where you wanted the information panel, you should put an information **LABEL** (JLabel) instead, because they hold text. `JLabel topRight = new JLabel();` then set the text, position, etc.

p.s. to erase the borders around every tile (if you want to do so), use `setBorderPainted(false)`.